# Enclose Multiline text inside quotes for a specific Regular Expression Capture Group

Tags: regex, csv

My input is text from different sources and the only consistent thing is that they all contain a code, latitude and longitude. This is sometimes followed by useful notes.

From this input, the aim is to produce a CSV format with the header row:
**Code,Name,Latitude,Longitude,Notes,URL,Comments**

Only the **Code, Latitude, Longitude** and possible **Notes** are required,

Using PCRE2, the substution string is
Code,,Latitude,Longitude,"Notes",,

```
$1,,$2,$3,"$4",,
```

My RE is almost doing what I want

```
(?mi)^.*?((?:\bGC)[A-Z0-9-]{1,10}).*?([N|S]\s?\d{1,2}°?\s+\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}'?).*?([E|W]\s?\d{1,3}°?\s+\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}'?)\s(.*)
```

You can check my work so far in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DSDGYH/1).

Focusing on part of the output in the example

```
GC8DH0G,,N 50° 50.456',W 001° 10.456',"Text to capture",,
Including line breaks and text, until the next GCcode
GC123GHF,,N 50 50.789,W 001 10.789,"etc.",,
```

The only additional requirement is to include all the multilines of text that follow the Longitude, up until the following GC code, also enclosed in quoted capture group 4.

So the above output would become

```
GC8DH0G,,N 50° 50.456',W 001° 10.456',"Text to capture
Including line breaks and text, until the next GCcode",,
GC123GHF,,N 50 50.789,W 001 10.789,"etc.",,
```

That is, all the text, including new lines \n or \r\n all enclosed in quotes.

Comment: A single quote and/or degree symbol (`°`) appears in the latitude and longitude fields in some, but not all, records. You might consider removing those characters in a pre-processing step, to simplify the regex, facilitate testing and streamline use of the CSV file. Yes, those characters could be sidestepped in the regex, but it would make a complex regex even more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this pattern, making use of PCRE freespacing mode and subroutine definitions. I borrowed your code for Latitude and Longitude definitions (changing `°` to `\x{00b0}` as suggested by @Reilas).

```
(?x) # make use of PCRE freespacing mode for better readability
(?(DEFINE) # define capture group behavior
  (?P<code_pattern> # GC code pattern
    GC # GC ...
    # ... followed by capital letters, digits and "-" 1 trough 10 times
    [A-Z0-9-]{1,10} 
  ) # end code_pattern
  # pattern to match lat and long locations
  (?P<location_pattern>
    \s? # optional space
    \d{1,3} # one or two digits
    \x{00b0}? # unicode of "°"
    \s+ # any number of spaces
    \d{1,2} # 1 or 2 digits
    \. # literal "."
    \d{1,3} # 1 through 2 digits
    '?
  ) # end location_pattern
  (?P<latitude_pattern>
    [NS] # "N" or "S"
    (?P>location_pattern)
  )
  # longitude analogous to
  (?P<longitude_pattern>
    [EW] # "E" or "W"
    (?P>location_pattern)
  )
  # pattern checking if current line contains a code
  (?P<check_for_code>
    (?!.*(?P>code_pattern))
  )
  # pattern to match notes
  (?P<notes_pattern>
    # note is only eligible if line has no more code
    (?P>check_for_code)
    .* # matches line 
    (?: # possibly ...
      \n # ... match new lines ...
      (?P>check_for_code) # ... if they contain no code
      .* # matches line
    )*
  ) # end notes_pattern
) # end definitions

#### ACTUAL PATTERN ####

# match unwanted initial characters so they can be replaced by an empty string
.* 
(?P<Code>(?P>code_pattern)) # capture Code
.*? # followed (lazily) by anything
(?P<Latitude>(?P>latitude_pattern)) # capture Latitude
.*? # followed (lazily) by anything
(?P<Longitude>(?P>longitude_pattern)) # capture Longitude
\s? # by optional space
(?P<Notes>(?P>notes_pattern))? # capture Notes (optional)
```

replace with:

```
$Code,,$Latitude,$Longitude,"$Notes",,\n
```

See https://regex101.com/r/2a7AG7/latest

If you need to get rid of empty lines in CSV further substitute `^$\n` with an empty string.

See https://regex101.com/r/Mj6rH7/latest

Comment: your solution outputs my requirement exactly. Thank you.

I also learnt a lot from your verbose comments in the pattern, much of which is new to me.

I can confirm that all Coordinates from source input will be in DDM format.

Comment: Well done! I finally understood what you were saying about my misunderstanding of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pattern fails if the source is extended as follows  
  
~~~~
GC8EYCQ Text to ignore N 50° 50.123,W 001° 10.123
GC8RCJR : N 53° 42.882' E 010° 36.354'
GC90MWV : N 53° 43.277' E 010° 37.509'
This is some text on a single line
After a newline we have more text
and a third line of text
Can all these lines be included as the fourth group of the previous GC Lat Lon line?
GC43G43 : N 53° 43.343' E 010° 43.343'
~~~~
  
The second Code is being seen as a Note of the first Code.  
  
Each Code must always be Capture 1

Comment: @user2631949 please verify that it now works as you would want it to.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland thank you for pointing this out! I did indeed copy it from the question!

Comment: @DuesserBaest I added a couple of extra lines that are not followed by any Notes to the source text. Each new Code must start on a new line to be CSV compliant but this is not the case. I have added some sample text to your solution and you can view it at https://regex101.com/r/FAFfY1/1

Comment: @user2631949 Please try again now

Comment: @DuesserBaest Perfect but ... there are four redundant blank lines in the output. Can they be eliminated in the Pattern? Thanks for all your additional help in solving this for me. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256116/discussion-between-duesserbaest-and-user2631949).

Comment: Although I would like to, I am unable to use free spacing mode in my programming code. Is there a way to easily convert an example like this: https://regex101.com/r/Mj6rH7/latest into a single line string?
I can only use $n substitutions: `$1,,$2,$3,"$4",,`

Comment: You can convert it with my conversion regex ^^ see: https://regex101.com/r/OOVV1w/latest. Then you can play with the numeric replacements and see that the groups are not [7,8,9,190] so the replacement becomes: `$7,,$8,$9,"$10",,\n`. Put together, find it here: https://regex101.com/r/6U8UXd/latest. To then get rid of empty lines in CSV, as mentioned in the post, use https://regex101.com/r/Mj6rH7/latest. Best of luck with the regex :)

Comment: Thank you ex @DuesserBaest for all your support on this. I can see from your examples that all patterns work perfectly. I tested in my code environment and got an error: Error in regex at offset 3: assertion expected after (?(. I then tested in Notepad++ and we have: Invalid Regular Expression. After a bit of research, Notepad++ uses Boost 1.55 and my application uses PCRE (I was wrongly of the belief it supported PCRE2. Sorry).

Comment: I guess I am going to have to drop the subroutines and repeat the patterns in places where they are called. I have learnt a lot from this thread and it looks like I am going to have to work with these dinosaurs (Unless there is a way to stay DRY with PCRE?).

Comment: @DuesserBaest, Here's my attempt to convert to PCRE but it is not giving the same output as yours. https://regex101.com/r/dtP0eo/1. I had to use the degree symbol.

Comment: try now at https://regex101.com/r/dtP0eo/latest. I think you went wrong after the newline statement for the note. you "incorectly" test if the newline starts with a GC pattern rather than using a negative lookahead to test whether no GC pattern would be present (and if so matching the line as additional note)

Comment: Testing in Notepad++ and my app, the additional lines of text are not included inside the quotes of capture group 4. Perhaps one of the lookarounds used is not supported in PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... My input is text from different sources and the only consistent thing is that they all contain a code, latitude and longitude. ..."*

To note, a resource will typically include a documentation outlining the syntax.

Regardless, there are different notations used for *[geographic coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system)* values.
The one you're parsing here is referred to as *DDM*, or *"degrees, decimal-minutes"*.
Subsequently, there is *DMS*, or *"degrees, minutes, seconds"*.
And, there is also, *DD*, or *"[decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)"*.

Here is a *capture pattern*.
The *[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)* *code-point*, *U+00b0*, is for the degree character, `°`.

```
(GC[A-Z\d]+).*?([NS] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]?),([EW] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]?|$)?
```

```
GC8EYCQ, N 50° 50.123, W 001° 10.123
GC8DH0G, N 50° 50.456', W 001° 10.456'
GC123GHF, N 50 50.789, W 001 10.789
GC123ABC, N 50 50.987, W 001 10.987
```

Additionally, here is a *pattern* for a *DMS* value.

```
(GC[A-Z\d]+).*?([NS] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+[^ ]? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]+),([EW] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+[^ ]? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]+|$)?
```

> *"... The only additional requirement is to include all the multilines of text that follow the Longitude, up until the following GC code, also enclosed in quoted capture group 4. ..."*

Try the following.
Essentially, if the coordinates are followed by anything other than white-space, capture the content, up unto the next *GC* code.

```
(?: *$|(?s) *(.+?)\s*(?=GC[A-Z\d]+))
```

Here is the re-factor.

```
(GC[A-Z\d]+).*?([NS] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]?),([EW] \d+\x{00b0}? \d+(?:\.\d+)?[^,\s]?|$)?(?: *$|(?s) *(.+?)\s*(?=GC[A-Z\d]+))
```

Here is the capture, I've replaced the new-line delimiters with `\n`.

```
GC8EYCQ, N 50° 50.123, W 001° 10.123, ""
GC8DH0G, N 50° 50.456', W 001° 10.456', "Text to capture\nIncluding line breaks and text, until the next GCcode"
GC123GHF, N 50 50.789, W 001 10.789, "More multiline text \nthat must be enclose in quotes\nNot just the first line of text to capture"
GC123ABC, N 50 50.987, W 001 10.987, ""
```

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but what was your reason for using `U+00b0` rather than `°` in your regex?